Running a step after a matrix step is done executing in GitHub Actions
I have one main job. Its first step checks out to the repo and creates a bunch of files in the repository using a matrix strategy. Now, I want to make a single git commit and push it into the repository. (I'm using an action for committing and pushing)
name: Testing the action

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  creating-files:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        file: [a.txt, b.txt, c.txt]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Creating the files
        run: touch ${{ matrix.file }}

      - name: Commiting
        uses: EndBug/add-and-commit@v9
        with:
          default_author: github_actions
          message: 'files updated'

The issue is that if I include the committing step after the matrix step (just like above), it fails with the error message that I should git pull first and it only creates the first file. Even if I pull first, still it doesn't work.
I heard that I should use a separate job and make it dependent on the first job (like need: creating-files). It's said that it makes sure once my first job is complete (meaning all the files are created), then committing starts, but there is an issue here too. The second job doesn't have access to the changed files from the first job and I'm not sure if "Artifacts" may be helpful.

artifacts will help you get the files into later jobs, so that makes sense to me.
